# Why can't I get the output of a 74LS221 to idle at 5 VDC?

Tags: ttl, schottky

I have an industrial machine with an encoder feeding a Measurement Computing USB-CTR08 counter board.

In order for the board to count the pulses the counter's gate `C0GT` needs to be held at a positive level, basically 5 VDC. With the 74LS221 disconnected, if I connect `C0GT` to 5 VDC it counts the pulses as expected. Disconnecting 5 VDC to allow the 'COGT' input to float, or connecting it to 0 VDC, causes the count to reset to 0. This is desired behavior.

In the machine there is a homing lug that passes an NPN sensor that is connected to a Phoenix Contact solid state relay to convert the pulse from 24 VDC to 5 VDC. When the lug makes the sensor the signal drops to 0 VDC for a short time and this is passed on to the 74LS221 monostable-multivibrator. I am using this for a short duration one-shot.

In this configuration when the lug pulse goes low, a single 155 ns pulse is to be generated on `not 1Q`. This pulse is supposed to go from high to low. Causing the counter to reset and start over each time the machine is in home position.

My problem is that the idle output is only about 2 VDC.  I tried a 1K pull up resistor tied to 5 VDC, but it didn't make a difference.

The table for the configuration on the `74LS221` looks like this:

```
   Inputs     |  Outputs
Clear  A   B  |  Q     !Q
  L    X   X  |  L      H
  X    H   X  |  L      H
  X    X   L  |  L      H
  H    L   Up |  Up    Down
              | Pulse  Pulse
              |
  H   Down H  |  Up    Down    <- My configuration
              | Pulse  Pulse
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAsbbs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Additional info 9 Feb 2019**

The counter board is a Measurement Computing USB-CTR08-OEM. The specifications on the reset gate in question:

[Measurement Computing USB-CTR08-OEM Product Data Sheet](https://www.mccdaq.com/GetPDF.aspx?t=/PDFs/specs/DS-USB-CTR-Series-data.pdf)

Input type: Schmidt trigger, 47K ohm pull down to ground with 33 ohm in series.
Schmidt trigger hysteresis: 0.76 V Typical, 0.4V minimum, 1.2V maximum.
Input high voltage threshold: 1.74V Typical, 1.3V minimum, 2.2V maximum
Input high voltage limit: 5.5 V absolute maximum
Input low voltage threshold: 0.98V Typical, 0.6V minimum, 1.5V maximum
Input low voltage limit: -0.5 V absolute minimum

I made another circuit using the original 74121 (note that it is not an LS part) that was used two years ago and it works. I'm assuming that a 74221 would probably work, but the LS version doesn't.

Comment: Is something else loading your 221 output (have you snuk a LED to ground on there to indicate the state, without telling us?)? Is the count input of the board rated to be driven by something as weedy as a 221, or is it intended to be driven by switch contacts. When you pull it to 5v with a DMM set to mA, how much current does it require?

Comment: The output of the 74LS221 goes to a terminal block and then the counter, nothing else. There is about 24" of 22 gauge wire in between. I will check the current later today.

Comment: We need to know what is inside the counter. Please provide a link to a datasheet for that device along with your current measurement.

Comment: @Rich: I've tidied up the schematic a little by using GND symbols to eliminate a bunch of 0 V wiring and declutter it. I hope that's OK.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the 221 output with a scope? It's possible that the unused half of the IC, being left floating, is doing something weird and causing the desired output to have a pulse train when you think it's just sitting there. That would explain the apparent low voltage. Also, for what it's worth, TTL outputs NEVER sit at 5 volts, so you should adjust your expectations.